# 2.8 Animation stops when copying keyframes in dopesheet

Tags: keyframes

I have been searching and i've found posts that touch on this issue but one that quite covered a solution.

I've got this fish and it has been animated and I am trying to copy the keyframes so that i can continually loop the animation of the fish.

I have gone into the NLA and unpinned the actions in there (as recommended in another post I found) but even still, whenever I copy and paste the keyframes the animation doesn't continue.

This image, you can see the un highlighted key frames, then in yellow is all of the keyframes I have copy and pasted - but as I play through, the animation only happens in the beginning (unhighlighted keyframes).

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I'm in Blender 2.8 on a standard 2016 Mac pro 15 inch.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting your question so clearly.
1. Go to GRAPH editor. Select all your keyframes. Then, SHIFT+E (for extrapolation options) > CYCLES. Your animation will last as long as you have animation timeline set end frames.

[image]

Thank you for your consideration to vote me up (click on the checkmark besides this post) as the answer.

BFCT_Schiller